# 'Low Disk Space' warning received when disk is nowhere near full

Tags: 13.04, disk-usage

I noticed this warning because it stops one of my applications (BOINC) from being able to work on a number of BOINC projects.

The 'Low Disk Space' warning says that I have 1.1GB remaining. I cannot work out where that number comes from.

The OS is installed on **sda1** which is a 256GB SSD.

I use a HDD **sdb1** of 1000GB (984.4GB formatted) to store my own bits and bobs.

I've been looking for the problem but I'm obviously out of my depth.

**sda1** shows in Properties as having 31.8GB used with 151.2GB free.

**sdb1** shows in Properties as having 375.2GB used with 559.2GB free.

What the devil is going on?

Comment: I took 5 relevant screenshots but I can't find anywhere to attach them.

Comment: upload the screenshots to imgur.com and then provide the links here.

Comment: What is the output of `df -h`?

Comment: Output from df -h:

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       204G   52G  142G  27% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.3M  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G  404K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       917G  350G  521G  41% /media/sdb1
el_gallo_azul@greg-W2600CR:~$

Comment: I hope that this link to imgur works:

http://imgur.com/a/fvy3R

Comment: That 'df -h' posting is worthless. I'll do it again and add a screenshot to imgur....http://imgur.com/dSErjTh

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Is this `df -h` output from the time when you receive the error message? Does the error message pop-up just after boot, or it pops up later on, while your softwares (e.g. BOINC) is been working for a while?

Comment: This `df -h` output is from after one instance of receiving the Low Disk Space warning message, and before another one (the next day).

I haven't received that message for more than a week, probably because I stopped running nearly all projects on BOINC, in order to reduce the number of write cycles and warnings occurring while I try to solve this mystery.

Comment: Also, to answer your second question, I remember the warning message as appearing shortly after boot, and I can't be sure whether it was related to BOINC running for a period of time first.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Bleachbit from the Software Centre and ticking the necessary scan boxes will help clean up your hard-drive's junk and temp files and save you some much needed space...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I won't do this for the moment because there is plenty of space on both my drives.